# rsync filter excluding everything but given (sub) directories

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I want to do a Linux system backup with `rsync` and my backup strategy ***exclude everything except what I explicitely want***. I am not succeeding in finding the correct filter rules.

I have the file `sync_filter`:

```
+ /etc
+ /home
+ /opt
+ /root
+ /srv
+ /var/backup
+ /var/log
+ /var/mail
+ /var/www
- /*
```

I think, my intention is clear. I want to include `/etc` and so on, I want to include `/var/log` and `/var/mail` but I **do not** want to include `/var/cache`.

I am not succeeding on the `/var` part.

Running `rsync -av --filter "merge sync_filter" --delete root@remote:/ .` will skip the `/var` part completely.

From the documentation, I understand that, e.g. `/var/backup` is skipped, because `/var` is excluded by `- /*` filter.

I also know that I could include `+ /var` and exclude, e.g. `- /var/cache` but I'd like to succeed with my backup strategy ***exclude everything except what I explicitely want***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution right afterwards. The filters have to be:

```
+ /etc
+ /home
+ /opt
+ /root
+ /srv
+ /var
+ /var/backup
+ /var/log
+ /var/mail
+ /var/www
- /var/*
- /*
```